# Assigning text to Reader.GetString() value?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=test"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from test.boxinformation where Box_SN='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        While READER.Read
            Dim CP = READER.GetString("CP_IP")
            Dim PC = READER.GetString("PC_IP")
            Dim M1 = READER.GetString("M1_IP")
            Dim M2 = READER.GetString("M2_IP")
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(CP)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(PC)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(M1)
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(M2)
        End While

        MySqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Basically, what is happening is I have a SQL Database full of IP Addresses that are specific to a Component. So when the user chooses the Component in ComboBox1, the IP address, specific to that Component, will populate in the ComboBox2.

My database is set up in a table containing 5 columns. ComboBox1 is pulling data from the column called "Box_SN" and ComboBox2 is pulling data from the column called "CP_IP", "PC_IP", "M1_IP" and "M2_IP". When the user makes a selection in ComboBox1, the IP address, that is associated with the chose component in ComboBox1, will then show in ComboBox2. So right now there are 4 IP addresses that populate in ComboBox2, and those IP addresses are specific to the selected box in ComboBox1. All of that is working the way it should be.

But instead of displaying the IP addresses in ComboBox2, I want to display text. So for "CP_IP", rather than displaying its IP address, I want it to display "Component A" and for "PC_IP" I want it to display "Component B"

So I guess what I am trying to say is that I want to assign the IP address, that I am bringing in through my database, to text and not just the IP that is being read in.

If anyone could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. Google "parameterized queries" to learn how to do it right.

Comment: The title makes no sense - you cant assign text to a function return.  I am *guessing* that the table holds the name you want *and* the IP address and you want to show one to the user but have the other for use in code???

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the web, html `select` elements have options with both content and values. In Windows Forms, the ComboBox elements just have `Objects`. It's common to just use string objects.

But.

You can put any kind of object you want in there, as long as the `.ToString()` method will produce something meaningful. These, for example:

```vb
Public Class ComboItem(Of T)
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Value As T

    Public Sub New() 
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(name As String, value As T) 
        Me.Name = name 
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String {
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

And then, also taking the time to fix the gaping SQL injection issue, your original method looks like this:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim Query As String = "select * from test.boxinformation where Box_SN= @BoxSN ;"

    Using MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=NOTROOT;password=root;database=test"), _
          COMMAND As New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)

        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@BoxSN", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        MySqlConn.Open()

        Using READER As MySqlDataReader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()

            While READER.Read
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Component A", READER.GetString("CP_IP")))
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Component B", READER.GetString("PC_IP")))
                'Guessing at the names here, since they aren't in the question
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Machine 1", READER.GetString("M1_IP")))
                ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Machine 2", READER.GetString("M2_IP")))
            End While
            READER.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

And now when a user makes a selection in ComboBox two, they can make that choice based on "friendly" text, but you'll still have access to the IP value you need.

Finally, it's a good idea to move all your data access into a place separate from your UI, like this:

```vb
Public Module Data
    Private Const ConnectinString As String = "server=localhost;userid=NOTROOT;password=root;database=test"

    Public Function GetComponentIPs(BoxSN As String) As String()
        Dim Query As String = "select * from test.boxinformation where Box_SN= @BoxSN ;"

        Using MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
              COMMAND As New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)

            COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@BoxSN", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = BoxSN
            MySqlConn.Open()

            Dim result(3) As String
            Using READER As MySqlDataReader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
                While READER.Read
                    'You could also do this with Tuples, or make another custom object (class) to hold this data to keep things strongly-typed

                    result(0) = READER.GetString("CP_IP")
                    result(1) = READER.GetString("PC_IP")
                    result(2) = READER.GetString("M1_IP")
                    result(3) = READER.GetString("M2_IP")
                    Return result
                End While
           End Using
        End Using
        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```

And then call it from your original method like this:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        Dim IPs As String() = Data.GetComponentIPs(ComboBox1.Text)

        ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Component A", IPs(0)))
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Component B", IPs(1)))
        'Guessing at the names here, since they aren't in the question
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Machine 1", IPs(2)))
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(New ComboItem(Of String)("Machine 2", IPs(3)))
    Catch ex As MySqlException
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: When I create the ComboItem class, I get a couple errors. 1. Public Property String Name gives an error on "String" and says "Keyword is not valid as an identifier". 2. Public Property T Value gives an error on "T" and says " 'T' has the same name as a type parameter" and  error on "Value" and says "end of statement expected". Then I get errors were they are referenced in the rest of the class. I am pretty new to all of this, so I am sure that this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Try again. Adapting this from some old C#.

Comment: For "Dim result as string(3)" I get an error on 3 saying " Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers" and then on "result(0)" i get a warning saying "Variable 'result' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime." I also get warning on "end function" saying " function 'GetComponentIPs' doesn't return a value on all code paths.

Comment: Fixed those issues. That's what I get for typing directly into the reply window after using primarily C# over the last several weeks. But these are basic language syntax issues you ought to be able to fix on your own. If you can't handle that, even as a beginner, you'll continue to struggle with programming.